# How to pass JSON into function and read back its JSON value

Tags: javascript

Tried below codes to get back the JSON values from the function but receive error => SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

```
const data = {"name": "John Lemon", "age":44}

const getInformation = (data) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(obj.name)
}

getInformation()
```

Comment: pass in data parameter to the function?

Comment: `data` is not JSON, it's an object. You're not passing `data` into the function…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process data by passing in parameters or global variables.

In addition, there is no need to use `JSON.parse()` because `data` is already a json object.

### Pass data to method

```js
const data = {
  "name": "John Lemon",
  "age": 44
};

const getInformation = (data) => {
  console.log(data.name)
};

getInformation(data);
```

### Use global variables

```js
const data = {
  "name": "John Lemon",
  "age": 44
};

const getInformation = () => {
  console.log(data.name)
};

getInformation();
```

Comment: `data` is already ***an object***. JSON is always a *string*.